# Docker Ubuntu instance not connecting to the network

Tags: ubuntu, docker, macos-sierra

I am running Docker 1.12.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1. I have downloaded an Ubuntu 16.04 image which I intend to configure to use as the basis for my Webpack building on Bitbucket Pipelines.

There are a handful of questions on StackOverflow pertaining to this issue. I have followed them all, but yielding on meagre results.

It appears that my Ubuntu instance is not connected to the network. I know enough about networking to diagnose this problem, but not enough to investigate or fix. Can anyone help?

Comment: When you can diagnose it: What's the problem?

Comment: My apt-gets fail, saying there is no such package. I cannot perform any operation over the network.

Comment: So a `ping 8.8.8.8` does not work, while it works from other hosts? This site is about programming btw. so this will be closed, soon.

Comment: There's no need for the mild aggression. Close it if you must.

Comment: Aggression? Not at all.. was just a hint.

Comment: @serlingpa Can you please try it with Ubuntu 14.04? I have a feeling that Ubuntu 16.04 is not that stable and doesn't support many tasks

Comment: Sorry @ StevenKing, in a foul mood and I took it out on you! Thought you were _threatening_ to close it down. Gonna try 14.04, thanks @Techiee

Comment: Using 14.04 now. Problem solved! Thanks @Techiee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 14.04 will solve this problem. As Ubuntu 16.04 is not that stable to perform all your task. Also there are some network related issues in Ubuntu 16.04 which I have faced personally. Trying `Ubuntu 14.04 - Trusty` and `Ubuntu 12.04 - Precise` will not create these issues and solve most of your problems.